# Where is the file location for samsung notes/memos and/or can I recover these files if I deleted the app?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, files, notes

I backed up all the files on my S9+ because I wanted to reinstall my buggy samsung notes app, but it turns out notes doesn't fall under documents anymore and it has its own separate sync that needs to be toggled from a default off. I've tried using different recovery software but they're either shady or don't work. I'm open to trying to root the device but I wanted to see if anyone knew where in the Android the notes or memos files are located and if it is still possible to recover them. I had pretty important stuff in the notes which is why I'm so concerned. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you create a (different than Google) Samsung account? Also did you password/fingerprint protect your notes?

Comment: you can't recover, it's lost